# JavaScript onclick method, attach it to All Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have quite a few buttons that look like this in my html code

```
<li>
        <span class="avatar"><span class="status online"></span></span>
        <spa">
```

And this is my javascript function for myFunction()

```
var buttonState = 0;

function myFunction(){
    cons
        buttonState = 1;
        return;
    }
    if(buttonState == 1){
        buttonState = 0;
    }
}
```

Since I have multiple buttons, I cant just do onclick="myFunction()" for all of them because there is no way to tell between the id of the buttons AKA they are all of ID "addFriend" so the myFunction() will always default to the first button. There has to be a way to remedy this but i've researched it any found no good help guides. Anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: _'they are all of ID "addFriend"'_ This is the first issue you'll run into where things have the same ID.  IDs really ought to be unique.

Comment: You pass an argument (like unique id) to the function, in that way you can know which button was clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "this" inside your parentheses:

```js
function myFunction(pObject) {
  console.log(buttonState);
  if (buttonState == 0) {
    pObject.value = "Friend Request Pending";
    buttonState = 1;
    return;
  }
  if (buttonState == 1) {
    pObject.value = "+ Add Friend";
    buttonState = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="avatar">
    <span class="status online">
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="username">Barack Brobama
  </span>
  <input type="button" id="addFriend" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="submit" value="+ Add friend">
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for function

onclick="myFunction(this)"

then you function will be

```
   function myFunction(pObject){          
      console.log(pObject.getAttribute('state'));
      if(pObject.getAttribute('state') == '1'){
        pObject.value = '+ Add Friend';
        pObject.setAttribute('state', '0');
      }else{
        pObject.value = 'Friend Request Pending';
        pObject.setAttribute('state', '1');
      }
    }
```

and sate you can save in tag